# Exponential Back off for GCM using URLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, google-cloud-messaging, httprequest

Exponential Back Off mentioned in [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff#examples) is based on `HttpRequest` which is removed in SDK 23. I have implemented GCM and i want to integrate this feature without using legacy `HttpRequest` class. I am using `URLConnection` to send request. How to implenent Exponential Back Off without using `HttpRequest`?

Comment: I can't find any articles regarding exponential backoff using URLConnection. However, there's a similar [issue raised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809835/how-to-implement-httprequestretryhandler-with-exponential-backoff) here where [Guava Retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) was suggested. Hopefullt this can be of help.

Comment: @adjuremods i have seen that already. I am looking for APIs that are already present in source code. Thanks for help.